# Can I replace this code to use IN operator as well?

Tags: mysql, sql

Our code is using create/drop table, while generating VR4 queue orders in our database.

When number of websites is less than 250, code is using IN operator and generating reports.   `ce.website_id in (" . (join ",", @{$website_id}) . ")`

When we have more than 250 websites, our code is creating tables (name like Temp_tablename) and using table joining instead of IN operator. Can I replace this code to use IN operator as well? Will there be any performance issue, if IN operator is used with more input values?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/

Comment: In spite of the intelligent responses provided by others, I'd still be tempted to 'suck it and see'. My guess is that performance won't suffer much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Stan, using a temporary table rather than a large **IN** is the preferred way to go.

When MySQL gets a large data block from the user it stores it in a *temporary* table and uses a *JOIN* to look through it. This is *easier* for MySQL to do than to actually look for each of your values in the **IN** SQL part.

You can skip this temporary table, by first storing in a table your web site list:

```
REPLACE INTO tblWebSitesToHandle
(Session_ID, WebSite)
VALUES
('**unique_number**', '**website_id**'), 
('**unique_number**', '**website_id**'), ...
```

Where **unique_number** will be some number you chose, and then toss away once the query ends - but it will help you manage the list of websites to handle for your query

Then in your SQL that you are currently using instead of **IN (...)** you will do a **JOIN** to this table and select from it the relevant **Session_ID** record.

After that is done, just remove from **tblWebSitesToHandle** the Session_ID data, it is no longer needed (I believe).